# Why does my else statement in prolog execute even if it doesn't satisfy the condition?

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I am confused because the else clause is being executed even if it doesn't meet the condition.

```
printNum(A, B) :-
      A =< B,
      writeln(A),
      A1 is A + 1,
      ignore(printNum(A1, B))
   ;  A > B,
      writeln(error).
```

if you try to input `printNum(3, 6)` with this code, it outputs:

```
3
4
5
6
error
true
```

my expected result is:

```
3
4
5
6
true
```

since A !> B

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the problem is that the **or** operation is executed at the `ignore(printNum(A1, B)); A > B` line rather than being executed in the whole predicate. If you modify the code a little bit :

```
printNum(A, B) :- 
    (A =< B,
    writeln(A),
    A1 is A + 1,
    ignore(printNum(A1, B))
    ;
    A > B,
    writeln(error)).
```

This way, the logical **or** operation will work correctly, and you will get the desired output.

Comment: The `writeln(error)` part will never be used as `A =< B, A > B` cannot succeed.

Comment: The line breaks you use are irrelevant. The important part is that the operator `(,)/2` binds stronger than `(;)/2`. With additional parenthesizes, you can overrule that like you do.

Comment: by the way, when I tried to input `printNum(6,3)` it will display `false` instead of `error
true`

Comment: Hey, sorry about that. I missed to include the top statement into the disjunction, now it should also give 'error true' for 'printNum(6,3)'. You can look at the edited answer for the correction

Comment: I'm totally confused now.  How does parenthesizing the entire body make any difference?  The error is being printed because the recursion will eventually generate the goal `printNum(7,6)`.  The `A > B` part looks like it is intended to check that the initial inputs are sane, but also serves to stop the iteration, but these are separate concerns.

Comment: The edited variant shows the original behavior. It doesn't matter which line you put the `(;)/2` into!